# Better (looking) Xpages buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages

Trying to make better looking buttons in Xpages. I created a button using a css button generator and it looks ok, but not great.

[image: Buttons]

I really like the look of the buttons on [Oliver Busse's page](http://oliverbusse.notesx.net/Privat/osnippets.nsf/id/OBUE-99WUS3)

[image]

I want to use this for tags. And when the user selects a button I want to highlight that one and all others to be de-highlighted.

I believe that Oliver is using bootstrap and I would like to do that, but I don't think I can import the entire framework now.

Here is my Xpages code and my css:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/buttons.css"></xp:styleSheet>
        <xp:script src="/xpUtilities.jss" clientSide="false"></xp:script>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:var arr = @Unique(@Trim(@DbColumn(@DbName(),"page001",3)));
    if (arr.length > 1) {arr.sort();}
viewScope.put("tags",arr);}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>

    <xp:panel style="padding-bottom:5.0px;padding-top:5.0px">
        <xp:label value="Filter By..." id="label1"></xp:label>
    </xp:panel>
    <xp:panel>
        <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="rowData" indexVar="index"
            value="#{tags}">
            <xp:button value="#{javascript:rowData}" id="button1"
                styleClass="button">
            </xp:button>
            &#160;&#160;&#160;
        </xp:repeat>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

css

```
.button {
   border-top: 1px solid #999999;
   background: #999999;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#999999), to(#999999));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #999999, #999999);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #999999, #999999);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #999999, #999999);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #999999, #999999);
   padding: 3.5px 7px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: white;
   font-size: 10px !important;
   font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
   font-weight: bolder;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
.button:hover {
   border-top-color: #28597a;
   background: #28597a;
   color: #ccc;
   }
.button:active {
   border-top-color: #1b435e;
   background: #1b435e;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to include original Bootstrap framework then copy css settings for elements you want to copy.

In this case, click on one of Oliver's buttons with right mouse button and choose "Inspect element". Then look at the right window for css styling and copy the relevant parts into your css file.

[image]

Set an additional style class "button-active" for last selected tag. Add this class with the help of a viewScope variable if you partially refresh or a sessionScope variable if you redirect to another XPage on click event.

Your example would change to:

```xml
<xp:panel>
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="100" var="rowData"
        value="#{tags}">
        <xp:button value="#{javascript:rowData}" id="button1"
            styleClass="#{javascript: 'button' + 
                                      (viewScope.tag == rowData ? ' button-active' : '')}">
            <xp:eventHandler
                event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="partial" refreshId="repeat1">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                    viewScope.tag = rowData;
                    // your action here
                }]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
        &#160;&#160;&#160;
    </xp:repeat>
</xp:panel>
```

css:

```css
.button {
    padding-left: 9px;
    padding-right: 9px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
    -moz-border-radius: 9px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    background-color: #999999;
    border:0;
}

.button:hover {
    border-top-color: #28597a;
    background: #28597a;
    color: #ccc;
}

.button:active, .button-active {
    border-top-color: #1b435e;
    background: #1b435e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am using Bootstrap and those tags are "badges" which result in this design. But my links are links and not buttons. So you want to highlight the selected tag by the value. Just change the classname of the link depending on a scope variable you set when clicking the link. 
You can download the OSnippets template from my Github repo to get an idea or just to play around with it: https://github.com/zeromancer1972/OSnippets

Comment: Oliver, that would be great. I downloaded the OSnippets github, but I have never understood how I go from the folder structure I get from zip hub and get that stuff into an NSF so I can look at. Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Looks like I just drag the elements into the correct place in package explorer.

Comment: No, just switch to the package explorer or navigator view (Windows, Eclipse Views, Navigator), right click in the navigator, Import..., Existing project into workspace. Then on the imported project (a yellow-blue folder) right click, team development, associate with new NSF. This creates a NSF from the structure on your server or local. Then you can open the NSF in DDE. I made a video here that shows it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y9d6KhbVkYk

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is badge from [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#badges).

If you look in the code of [Oliver Busse's page](http://oliverbusse.notesx.net/Privat/osnippets.nsf/id/OBUE-99WUS3), you can see `<span class="badge">XSP</span>` (bootstrap 2), which confirms what I say.